# Javascript - Call a function within a function?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onchange, breezingforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript “onchange” inside Breezingforms framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848393/javascript-onchange-inside-breezingforms-framework)

Within the function below, how can I call this function:  `logo_prodImgBySel('theImg',this.selectedIndex)`

```
function ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action(element, action)
{
switch (action) {
    case 'change':     WHAT CODE SHOULD GO HERE???
  break;
    default:;
} // switch
} // ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action
```

I'm not sure of the location in this code block to call this function (which was defined earlier in the document.  I'm working within requirements of a Joomla form builder.

Comment: not sure what you're having trouble with. Have you tried just calling the function where you have `WHAT CODE...`? Let us know what problems you've run into.

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't perform the function: 
function ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action(element, action)
{
switch (action) {
    case 'change':     logo_prodImgBySel('theImg',this.selectedIndex);
  break;
    default:;
} // switch
} // ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action

Comment: can u show some code to understand. which function are you trying to call? what error do u get? where's function defined

Comment: have you tried looking at your javascript console to see if you're getting errors? We need to know what the problem is in order to fix it.

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, what happens when you reach that line? Do you get an error message? (My guess is that `this` is not set correctly, but there is not enough information to know for sure.)

Comment: I'm new to javascript, and I just don't know the appropriate way to call the function.  Are you saying that it appears to be correct in my previous comment?  Where can I debug the script?

Comment: I'm guilty for double posting, so I apologize.  But here is a more thorough explanation of what is going on.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848393/javascript-onchange-inside-breezingforms-framework

Comment: On this page, you can see the function working in the field labeled "product line"...this is me controlling the onchange event directly in html.  You can also see the function not working in the field labled "BF Select List".  The latter is using the tool called Breezing Forms which requires me to work withing their function framework.  http://logochairs.com/j25cms/index.php/customform/bf-form-test

Comment: Further, for reasons I'll spare you, I need to get this working in the select list called "BF Select List" instead of the field I made myself called "Product Line"

Comment: Have I lost everyone now?  Seems the post has been voted down and everyone disappeared.  Can you offer some constructive pointers to get the question answered/ ask it differently etc?

Comment: Yes, don't post the same question twice and then not provide enough information to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action(element, action)
{
switch (action) {
    case 'change': logo_prodImgBySel('theImg',this.selectedIndex);
  break;
    default:;
} // switch
} // ff_bfQuickMode1482721_action
```

Comment: This is currently what I have on the page, but it doesn't perform the function.